# How to split on commas and dot?

Tags: python, regex, string, replace, split

You are given a string consisting only of digits, commas, and dots. Your task is to complete the `regex_pattern` defined below, which will be used to `re.split()` all of the `,` and `.` symbols in. It's guaranteed that every comma and every dot in is preceded and followed by a digit.

```
Sample Input 0

100,000,000.000

Sample Output 0
```

I am using Python 3.7.2 and I tried `re.split` by using `\,*` and `\.*` as shown below in the code but it seems to print after every numeral.

```
regex_pattern = r"\,*\.*"

import re
print("\n".join(re.split(regex_pattern, input())))
```

However, this seems to be printing in the wrong order.

What should I add in `regex_pattern`?

Expected result was:

```
100
000
000
000
```

However, I am getting:

```
1   
0   
0   

0   
0   
0   

0   
0   
0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```py
string = "100,000,000.000"

regex_pattern = r"[,.]"

import re
print("\n".join(re.split(regex_pattern, string)))
```

```
100
000
000
000
```

Edit: Fixed the pattern based on the solution [Diwakar SHARMA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6347132/diwakar-sharma) added to the comments.

Comment: just for your info mine worked too :regex_pattern = r"[,.]" # Do not delete 'r'.

import re
print("\n".join(re.split(regex_pattern, input())))

Comment: Yep, your simpler patter works as well! Thanks for adding

Comment: FYI: `[\,|\.]` matches comma or pipe or dot. Ther're no needs to escape comma and dot in a character class, your regex can be simplified as `r"[,.]"`

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is quite close to working as expected. Your regex uses the `*` wildcard, which matches 0 or more instances of the character it follows, in your case `,` and `.` literals. The subtle thing here is that they can both be exactly zero matches, so it will split between every character!

To improve your regex to do what you were intending, you could modify it to use the `+` wildcard, which matches one or more of the character. Strictly speaking you probably only have exactly one of the character, in which case you may not need a quantifier at all! If you use the `+` wildcard however, you will also need to add in the `|` operator so it matches either `,` or `.`.

Ultimately, your regular expression should look like `r"\,+|\.+"` or better yet, use `[]` group like so `r"[\,\.]"`, which will match exactly one`,` or `.`. Add the `+` wildcard to match one or more.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do the job is to replace comma and dot with linebreak:

```
import re

string = "100,000,000.000"
print re.sub(r"[,.]", '\n', string)
```

**Output:**

```
100
000
000
000
```